# Unresolvable build extension: Plugin com.opencloud.maven.plugins:maven-opencloud-jainslee-plugin:1.1

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, telecommunication, jain-slee

I am getting below error when I run any maven command like `mvn clean` or `mvn clean install` or `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

But I am able to run any other maven project other than this in my system so I am sure it is not related to path issues or with proxy.

Below is my error

> 1.[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]    org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were
>   encountered while processing the POMs:
>
> 2.[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.opencloud.maven.plugins:maven-opencloud-jainslee-plugin:1.1 or one
>   of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find 
>       "com.opencloud.maven.plugins:maven-opencloud-jainslee-plugin:jar:1.1"
>   in "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @
>
> 3.[ERROR] Unknown packaging:"

I Generated sbb files with maven command,
`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://developer.opencloud.com/maven2/public` it generated successfully.

But when build it with mvn clean install, it has above errors

Below is my POM.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bt</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-sbb</artifactId>
    <packaging>jainslee-sbb-jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp SBB</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.slee</groupId>
            <artifactId>jainslee-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>jainslee-base-classes</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.opencloud.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-opencloud-jainslee-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jainsleeVersion>1.1</jainsleeVersion>
                    <createLibrary>true</createLibrary>
                    <createDeploymentUnit>true</createDeploymentUnit>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

I will get below error when I run maven clean in both command line and eclipse

`C:\Users\611542579\Documents\NOAS-CSG\Sample\com.bt>mvn clean`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project myApp:com.bt-sbb:1.0-SNAPSHOT
      (C:\Users\611542579\Documents\NOAS-CSG\Sample\com.bt\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Error resolving version for plugin
     'com.opencloud.maven.plugins:maven-opencloud-jainslee-plugin'
      from the repositories
         [local (C:\Users\611542579\.m2\repository),
         central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]:
         Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: jainslee-sbb-jar @ line 7, column 16
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this in your pom:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jainslee</id>
        <name>Jainslee repos</name>
        <url>http://developer.opencloud.com/maven2/public</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

This

> http://developer.opencloud.com/maven2/public

is what you give in command line but is it in your pom also?

**It can be also** that there is a problem with your local maven repo. Try the following:

find corresponding path in your local maven repo

*{home}/.m2/repositories/com/opencloud/maven/plugins/maven-opencloud-jainslee-plugin*

and delete that directory. Try again.

**UPDATE**: take a look this part on the error message

```
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Error resolving version for plugin
     'com.opencloud.maven.plugins:maven-opencloud-jainslee-plugin'
      from the repositories
         [local (C:\Users\611542579\.m2\repository),
         central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]:
         Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 2]
```

You can see that plugin is first searched from your local then from central maven repository. It is not found there. It should be searched from here

> http://developer.opencloud.com/maven2/public

and that is why there is a need for that `<pluginRepositories>` part in your pom.

If you cannot edit the pom in question create dummy project, add this pluginRepository and plugin in that project, run it like `mvn install`: it should download plugin to your local repo.

Maybe then you are able to run original project in question without errors.

Comment: Hi Pirho, Thanks for reply. It is autogenerated POM when I run mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://developer.opencloud.com/maven2/public command. It is working in other systems. But it is strange I am getting this issue.

Comment: @chethanbhounsleyg can you edit your question providing information about these  _system_ s what are those and in which works / not work?

Comment: Hi Pirho, other system  mean my team members,, I have edited my question posted error below POM.xml. Tried your approches by deleting plugin folder inside m2 but no luck !!